# python - How to count number of files recursively in a path using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Lets suppose I have a single node with infinite number of CPUs and infinite I/O resources. I would like to write a python script which uses multiprocessing and calculates the total amount of files in a given path and all the subdirectories

example:

I run a script which generates millions of files in a given path:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NUMDIRS=300000
NUMFILES=10

myPath="/tmp/test"

echo "Working on path: $myPath"

for directory in `seq 1 $NUMDIRS`
do
    mkdir -p "$myPath/$directory"
    cd $myPath/$directory
    for file in `seq 1 $NUMFILES`
    do
        touch "file_$file.txt"
        echo "Path:       $myPath/$directory" >> file_$file.txt
        echo "Filename:   file_$file.txt" >> file_$file.txt
        echo "Created on: `date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`" >> file_$file.txt
    done
done
```

Even if this is not the best example to use multiprocessing, just for learning purposes, I would like to know how I could write a python piece of code to use multiprocessing and return 3000000 following the provided example (300000 directories x 10 files per directory).

**EDIT:**
A first unsuccessful approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import multiprocessing


path = "/tmp/test"


def count_single_process(path):
    cpt = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(path)])
    return cpt


def walkingThePath(path):
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        return len(f)


def main():
    cpu_number = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_number) as Pool:
        print(Pool.map(walkingThePath, path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What did you try (what Python code did you write) to solve this?

Comment: @ForceBru, to be absolutely honest I haven't tried to solve this example as I have no experience with multiprocessing. I have read online documentation and played around with the usual examples of time sleep(x) but I do not understand well how to make multiple simultaneous calls and add their result. If you recommend some reading, I will be glad to give it try. Thanks!

Comment: I am not a multiprocessing expert, but I would like to share my idea here (comments are welcome). I will just use a main process to collect available sub directories and assign a process to work on that sub directory (probably a multi-threaded BFS).

Comment: @ForceBru, I have edited the entry adding a first unsuccessful approach. Any guidance would be welcome. Thanks!